# flash actionscript 3.0 how to display integers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im new to flash - actionscript 3.0. I have created a text and i am able to set a string by doing txt.text = "something". My problem is, i want to display an integer instead of a string, how is this possible?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionScript is generally very forgiving when something needs to be cast to string and it will often do it for you. This should work:

```
var a:int = 1;
txt.text = a; // Now that I think of it, I forget if AS3 has issues with this. 
              // AS2 does not
```

If concatenating to a string, however, I recommend strict casting, as that will avoid an accidental NaN:

```
var a:int = 1;
var str:String = "foo";
txt.text = str + String( a ); // now "foo1"
```

Remember too, if adding to the end of a textfield's text (instead of assigning it), use appendText.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNumber:Number = 2;
txt.text = myNumber.valueOf(); //or txt.text = new String(2);
```

Comment: First, int not number. Second, use toString() instead of valueOf -- everything as a toString which retruns a String, sometimes valueOf returns a non-String value. Third, use of String constructor is faux pas.

Comment: Didn't really thought about whether it's an int or a Number. Thx for tip about valueOf(). Can't u provide any info about that. Could you please explain why the use of string constructor is faux pas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a [`NumberFormatter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/NumberFormatter.html). Here's [Adobe's example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/NumberFormatter.html#includeExamplesSummary) to get you started.

Comment: you don't need the flex framework just to show an integer in a textfield.  Cwallenpoole's answer is a lot simpler.

Comment: @frankhermes, I completely agree. I thought the OP wanted to format his string (ex. "12345") as a number. I upvoted cwallenpoole's answer as well.